# Unable to create new Team project over the internet getting SQl Reporting service resolve error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, tfs

Hi I have installed a Team Foundation Server 2010, and it works perfectly over my Lan, but I need it to work over the internet too.

My problem is that when Im connected to my team server over the internet, I get the following error, when I try to create a new Team project.

*TF218027: The following reporting folder could not be created on the server that is running SQL Server Reporting Service:
//TfsReports/myTeam. The report server is located at:
http://my-server/reports. The error is: The remote name could not be resolved: 'my-server'*

From the looks of it, its trying to resolve my lan name.
I have already made sure, that its possible to access the Sql server Reporting, from the internet, with this url. team.mywebsite.com/Reports and team.mywebsite.com/reportserver

What do I need to change, for it to use team.mywebsite.com instead of my-server

And just for the record, team foundation server 2010, Sql Server 2008 R2 and Sharepoint 2010 is all installed on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the url's where tfs is published in the TFS Server Administration Console.

There is several url's that you need to change, so that you can access all the parts of the tfs server from the outside using team.mywebsite.com and the project creation to be successful:

1. The tfs notification url. (Changed under the Application Tier node)
2. Sharepoint url (Changed under the SharePoint Web Applications node)
3. Reporting services ReportManager and webservice (Changed under the Reporting node)

Comment: Hi just a little update, im still working on it, but i think your answer is the right direction. Im using this guide as well http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2009/11/installing-sharepoint-2010-windows-2008.html

Comment: Thanks Martin Hyldahl, with your help, I was able to find this article http://www.tjopsta.net/index.php/2010/04/16/how-to-change-team-foundation-server-2010-urls-for-use-externally/ and now every thing works.  (Also great to meet an old dotnetforum.dk user :-) )

Comment: Great article you have found, looks like it describes all the steps to change the urls. (I were wondering if you where the gulbaek back from the dotnetforum.dk days. Great that we still can help each other out :-))