# TF218027 - I can't create a team project in Visual Studio with TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, windows-server-2008

I am trying to create a new project in team foundation server 2010 and get the error message:

[image]

I think the reason is, that the tfs tries to create a folder for the reporting service with the url http://s1/.... but the tfs runs on a root server, so I can not resolve the hostname s1. But I can't figure out yet, how to change this to the ip address of the server.

Comment: There are already threads on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3912608/147211) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3241420/147211)

Answer (score 0):

I think the account you login with, didn't has permission on the SSRS, to assign permission you can download the TFS Administration tool http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/ and assign your account high permission.

But my real advice to you, just try to install TFS in a right way, see this video guide
http://tfs10enterprise.codeplex.com/